# How to fetch posts that are stored in the different table than the default table (wp_posts)?

Tags: posts, post-meta, table

How can I Fetch posts that are stored in the different table than the default table (wp_posts)?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME));
```

Replace TABLE_NAME with your custom table name.

Comment: Where should I add this code?

Comment: the name of the table: blogb_posts

Comment: You can create a short code using this code and add the short code in your page template or in the edit page section. For short code please refer - https://speckyboy.com/getting-started-with-wordpress-shortcodes-examples/